# Can't Create JavaCC Template on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, compiler-construction, javacc

I've downloaded the latest plugin for Eclipse which is found Here: http://eclipse-javacc.sourceforge.net/

I'm going FILE > NEW > OTHER FILE > JAVACC > JavaCC Template

and when I try to create one, it doesn't let me choose a folder, it says it has no Sources. When I try to write one hard Coded (C:\Test) it says it doesn't exists even if it does

Any idea?

This is what it's showing me

[image: Problem]

Comment: Is it a Java project?  If so, have you defined one or more source folders?

Comment: no, it's a .JJ File, for Java CC. We're doing a Compiler for SXL using C++ and this JavaCC.

Comment: It may be that the wizard only works for Java projects. I'd suggest that you create the .jj file without using the plugin.  You can probably still use the plugin's editor if you want. Personally I'm not that fond of the editor.  Also to generate C++, you will need JavaCC 6.0 or greater.  The version shipped with the plugin is currently version 5.0.

Comment: could be it, thanks mate.. I actually switched to just notepad++ and then I'll compile it through cmd. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Just create the file manually via New / File wizard.

[image]

[image]

To compile with JavaCC 6.0+, first locate the file then set the jarfile for the plugin as shown below:

1) Go to properties on your project

[image: Go to properties on your project]

2) Click JavaCC Options:

[image]

3a) Click the 'browse' button next to the 'Set the JavaCC jar file' option.

[image]

3b) Now select the location of the JavaCC 6.0 or above jarfile.

[image]

3c) Now click 'OK' on the properties screen.

[image]

4) Now go to your .jj or .jjt file and right click, then select "Compile with JavaCC"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a project first (Menu > File > New > Project) then do the above step again and you'll be able to browse to a folder